# Кастомизация страницы "нет доступа" если у роли нет прав на просмотр

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, аутентификация

Делаю приложение ASP .NET Core, у меня есть контроллер, в котором описаны все административные действия, эти действия может делать только админ, т.е. я использую роли

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
```

Если зайти на страницу неавторизованным пользователем - меня кидает на страницу входа, окей.

А если в админ панель входит обычный юзер, а не админ, то его кидает на страницу с URL `AccessDenied?ReturnUrl=%2FAdmin%2FIndex`
содержимое которой `Status Code: 404; Not Found`

Можно ли как-то кастомизировать эту страницу?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В asp.net core 2.1 вы можете настроить отображение страницы /Identity/Account/AccessDenied

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Для этого вам необходимо в контекстном меню проекта выбрать Add - New scaffloded item, в появившемся меню выбрать пункт identity, а затем указать что вы хотите кастомизировать страницу Account\AccessDenied:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Текст этой страницы по умолчанию такой (можете поправить на тот, который вам нужен):

```
@page
@model AccessDeniedModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Access denied";
}

<header>
    <h1 class="text-danger">@ViewData["Title"]</h1>
    <p class="text-danger">You do not have access to this resource.</p>
</header>
```

Comment: @A K, вы не поняли меня, или я плохо составил вопрос. Если заходит аноним, то его, как и у вас на скрине кидает на страницу ввода логина и пароля. Но если заходит юзер, который ввел логин и пароль, но не попадает под роль - Админ, тогда я и сталкиваюсь со своей проблемой

Comment: @A K, вот, теперь то, что надо, AccessDenied - именно то, что я искал, спасибо)

Comment: @A K, подойдет, прошлый комментарий мой был к посту, когда вы еще не добавили инфу об AccessDenied)

Answer (score 2):

Есть методы для установки страниц с кодом состояний:

```
app.UseStatusCodePages();
app.UseStatusCodePages(Action<IApplicationBuilder>);
app.UseStatusCodePages(Func<StatusCodeContext,Task>);
```

C перенаправлением:

```
app.UseStatusCodePagesWithRedirects(string);
app.UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute(string with plaseholder, string);
```

[ИСТОЧНИК, тут с блекджеком и примерами!](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/aspnet/core/fundamentals/error-handling?view=aspnetcore-2.1#configure-status-code-pages)